# Gcloud app deploy. Stopping Master

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gunicorn, gcloud

I am trying to deploy my app to the app engine but for some reason, I can't do so. My logs says

> Shutting down master
>
> Reason: worker failed to boot

I think it has something to do with gunicorn. How do I go about this?

My app.yaml is

```
runtime: Python
 env: flex 
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT .wsgi
beta_settings:
      cloud_sql_instance: /*mysqlinstance*/
 runtime_config:
       python_version: 3
```

Comment: Can you please attach the redacted logs when you deploy using the --verbosity flag? Like so: 

     gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug

Comment: updating service [default] (this may take several minutes).../DEBUG: Operation [apps/sabilize-182111/operations/40439d2f-5e9e-4179-bb76-d7b9f72ea8e1] not complete. Waiting to retry.           This is where it stops

Comment: What else can I do?

Comment: Do you get same result when deploying the Google Cloud Shell? This would eliminate the possibility that it is a dev environment issue.

Comment: I got the same error when deploying with cloud shell: shutting down: master. Reason: worker failed to boot

Comment: IT'S WORKING NOW!!! MY APP IS WORKING NOW!!! YEAHHHHHH!!! THANK YOU FOR YOUR PATIENCE!!! HAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!!

Comment: Months of frustration have finally been solved

Comment: I am glad your issue has already been resolved. The community would appreciate it if you post your solution. It might help someone with the same error in the future. Thanks

Comment: Okay. I've done that

Answer (score 1):

So my solution:

I started afresh!

I created a new project in my cloud because a lot of complications had gotten into the one I was using. Then I included django==1.10 and gunicorn==19.7.1 in the requirements.txt file and ran

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

in the virtual environment and then deployed to the new project
Everything worked fine.